# Edit Information and Update Database via Front-End (HTML, CSS, PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I apologize in advance for the fact that I have little to no programming skills. I am in a group working on a web application (HTML, CSS, PHP, SQL) that allows exam scheduling for a fictional university. We are nearing the finish line but are at kind of a standstill right now - we figured out how to connect the front-end GUI to the back-end database and retrieve information; however, we cannot figure out how to make that retrieved information editable on the front-end so that the user can make changes and therefore update the database on the back-end. Can anyone help guide us in the right direction? I feel like we just need an "AHA" moment to get the ball rolling.

Below is a snippet of the code that retrieves the database information, albeit in an un-editable format. Thanks for any help you can provide :)

```
<%@taglib prefix="d" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>



<!doctype html>


<sql:query var="section" dataSource="jdbc/FESS_PROJECT_MJ">
SELECT DISTINCT call_number FROM courses ORDER BY call_number
</sql:query>



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>PFU Final Exams</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g2">
        <header id="h1">
            <center><h1>Welcome to PFU's Exam Scheduling System!</h1></center>
        </header>

        <header id="h2">
            <center><h2><b>Exam Schedules Page</b></h2></center>
        </header>

        <section id="s1">
            <header>

                <h3><center>Please make a selection from the drop menus below:</center>                 
</h3><br />            
</header>
        </section>

        <form action="ExamScheduleResponse.jsp">
            <strong>Please select a Section</strong>
            <select name="section">
                <d:forEach var="row" items="${section.rows}">
                    <option value="${row.call_number}">${row.call_number}</option>
                </d:forEach>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>            


        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

        <div><center>Section</center></div>

    </div>

    <div><center>Course Number</center></div>

</div>
<br />
<br />

<div><center>Instructor's Name</center></div> 

</div>
</form>
</section>
<br /><br />
<section id="s2">
<header>
    <h3><center>OR Select the Room Number from the drop menu below:</center></h3><br />
</header>
</section>

<div><center>Room Number</center></div>
<center><select name="Room"></center>
<option value=  "   room1   ">  003 </option>

</select> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need some text boxes in html and a form submit. You then use the POSTED information in some update queries in server side code. Watch out for SQL injection though!

Comment: Just to add on the above comment, if you do use a POST method it will redirect the browser to your post url (forexample processCode.php) then you'll need to send the user back or render success/failure on that php page. Also you need to add method="post" in your <form> tag. You mention php though, I see .jsp?

Answer (score 1):

You need some text boxes in html and a form submit. You then use the POSTED information in some update queries in server side code. Watch out for SQL injection though!

This may give you your AHA moment

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_update_php.htm

Answer (score 1):

The question could be a bit more specific... maybe update it with some more detail about what *exactly* you need to achieve.

In order to 'make the content editable' as you suggest, you need to create an interaction with the database.

Your form currently targets ExamScheduleResponse.jsp which is a java page, not a php page as your question appears to imply.

Assuming you were using PHP you would push to a php file that would run an INSERT or UPDATE query to change the data in the database.

---

### Basic Steps:

**Step 1.**

Validate the changes in javascript/jquery before pushing to the server
(correction loop)

**Step 2**

Push to the php/jsp page that will do the update/insert via form submission

**Step 4**

Push insert/update to database. send message back to user for success or failure (ajax or direct page)

If you are not sure how to do all of this securely or safely, I'd be inclined to suggest learning to use an MVC framework such as Symfony http://symfony.com/

---

### Tutorials:

This Tutorial might get you started:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

This Page specifically seems to be what you need.
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/7